# Android Analytics v4: 0 Length Session Duration

Tags: android, google-analytics

So I'm attempting to implement analytics, and I'm seeing page views in real time, but when I checked my session durations from yesterday I'm only seeing 0 length durations. My Application class initializes my tracker in onCreate():

```
Tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance( this ).newTracker( getString( R.string.ga_trackingId ) );
Tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking( true );
Tracker.setAppId( getString( R.string.app_name ) );
Tracker.setAppVersion( getMajorVersion() + "." + getMinorVersion() );
Tracker.set( "Android Resolution", getString( R.string.android_resolution ) );
```

where Tracker is defined as:

```
public static Tracker Tracker;
```

In my MainActivity I'm using onStart() and onStop() like so:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

and in my fragments I'm using code like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    TrackerUtil.sendAnalyticsPageView( getString( R.string.some_fragment_page_name) );
}
```

I also have an analytics.xml file with this content (obviously the UA id and package names are edited):

```
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX-Y</string>
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string> 
<string name="com.example.activity.MainActivity">HOME</string>
```

Any suggestions on what may be the problem? I'm using Play-Services 6.1.+

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the guidelines of the v4. You may have updated to Google Analytics to v4 but your implementation looks like v3.

In v4, to track activities you don't need to sent hit on `onStart()` and `onStop()`. So remove it from all you activity.

`analytics.xml` was in v3. Now in v4 there is new approach.

To track activities, create a file named `app_tracker.xml` in your `res/xml` folder like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX-Y</string>
      <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
      <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
      <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string> 
      <string name="com.example.activity.MainActivity">HOME</string>

       // Write all your screens here like HOME screen.
 </resources>
```

That's it.

You can read more at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/.

Answer (score 0):

Session length is defined by the time difference between the first and the last interactive hit that appear in the session. Periods without hits longer then the session timeout (default is 30 minutes) will start a new session. Most hits are considered interactive unless you set &ni=1 (non-interactive flag). If you see sessions with length of 0 you are likely sending single interactive hit for each session. Please note that hits without required params (like valid hit type, etc) are ignored and will not extend you session.

To verify, enable verbose logging and look at the logcat/GAV4 tag. Your session length will be the time difference between the first and the last log for sending interactive hits.

BTW, you can't set arbitrary params on the tracker. `Tracker.set("Android Resolution", ...)` has no effect and will be ignored. You should either use one of the provided tracker.setX methods or use valid [measurement protocol parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) prefixed with "&".